# How to display JSON output?

Tags: json, api, rest, powershell, jira-rest-api

First API to call:

```
https://proto123.hipchat.com/v2/user?auth_token=2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I get the user IDs when I run this URI.

Then I need to execute the next URI for each user ID generated from the previous URI:

```
https://proto123.hipchat.com/v2/user/id?auth_token=2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then print the output file to CSV.

How do I Do that?

Please check this script:

```
$uri = "https://proto123.hipchat.com/v2/user?auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
try {
  $webResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -ContentType "application/json"
} catch {
  $webResponse = $_.Exception.Response
}

if ($webResponse) {
  Write-Debug "Output result"

  $webResponseIDList = @() # Defining array for collecting the ID's
  foreach ($webResponseID in $webResponse) {
    $webResponseIDList += [PSCustomObject] @{
      id = $webResponseID.id
    } # End of ID's Array
    $id = $webResponseID.id

    Write-Host "User ID is : $id" + $webResponseIDList `r`n
    $uri = "https://proto123.hipchat.com/v2/user/$id?auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    $webResponseID = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -ContentType "application/json"

    Write-Host "User ID are :" + $webResponseID.id `r`n
    Write-Output "User ID are :" + $webResponseID.id `r`n
  }
} else {
  Write-Debug "No results were returned"
}
```

I am not getting the output in PowerShell.

Comment: Since you've already been so foreseeing as to add `Write-Debug` statements, why don't you use them to see where the problem is?

Comment: What does `$webResponse` look like?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
I've tried using the debug statements but i couldn't find the problem.
Is the script right or am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
foreach ($webResponseID in $webResponse) {
  ...
}
```

to

```
foreach ($webResponseID in $webResponse.items) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. That helped.. Can you check the edited script?
I need the participant name, id, in diff rows not in the same one.

Thank you.